# simpler way to breakdown string sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this function below I am breaking down a string like for example 
string = '100001|125000,50001 - 75000' end result table below is there a simpler way to do this?

```
     low     high
     100001  125000
     50001   75000


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRange] (@String varchar(max))
returns @temptable TABLE (low int, high int)  
as       
begin       

declare @separated table(items varchar(max))

insert into @separated select * from dbo.Split(@String, '|')

update @separated
set items = items + ',2147483647'
where charindex(',', items) = 0

insert into @temptable 
select left(items, charindex(',', items) - 1)
     , right(items, len(items) - charindex(',', items)) 
       from @separated
return       
end
```

Comment: what version of sql server? And is this the format for the column all the way through?

Comment: sql server 2012 yes

Comment: why the items + ',2147483647' ?

Comment: Throw few more string example and their output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you can remove the split function and replace it with a `UNION` and it *may* be faster. This would eliminate your function, and the nested function. I guess it depends on your use case. At a minimum it removes your `dbo.Split` function which hopefully is based off considerations [from this article.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) but if it isn't, it could be real slow.

```
declare @table table (a varchar(4000))

insert into @table (a) values
('100001|125000,50001 - 75000'),
('101321320001|1250132100,52130001 - 755000')

select
    left(left(a,charindex(',',a) - 1),charindex('|',left(a,charindex(',',a) - 1)) - 1) as Low
    ,right(left(a,charindex(',',a) - 1),len(left(a,charindex(',',a) - 1)) - charindex('|',left(a,charindex(',',a) - 1))) as High
from @table
union all
select
    left(right(a,len(a) - charindex(',',a)),CHARINDEX('-',right(a,len(a) - charindex(',',a))) - 1)
    ,right(right(a,len(a) - charindex(',',a)),len(right(a,len(a) - charindex(',',a))) - charindex('-',right(a,len(a) - charindex(',',a))))
from @table
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is assuming the Delimiter is a comma AND ranges may be split with a | or a dash.  You may notice that the dash is replaced with a | for consistency.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction] (@String varchar(max))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select Low  = try_convert(int,Left(RetVal,charindex('|',RetVal)-1))
          ,High = try_convert(int,Right(RetVal,charindex('|',reverse(RetVal))-1))
    From  (
            Select RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')))
            From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(@String,'-','|'),',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
            Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) B
)


Select * from [dbo].[TestFunction]('100001|125000,50001 - 75000')
```

Returns

```
Low     High
100001  125000
50001   75000
```